# Release Notes generation

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket, jira, release-notes

Is there a way to automatically generate Release Notes for releases in Azure DevOps pipeline but source code in BitBucket?

First, I tried extension [XplatGenerateReleaseNotes](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=richardfennellBM.BM-VSTS-XplatGenerateReleaseNotes) but it doesnt work with BitBucket due to [Azure DevOps API limitation](https://github.com/rfennell/AzurePipelines/issues/1003)

Second, I tried [Jira to Azure DevOps integration](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-jira/blob/master/tutorial.md) but again [it does not work with BitBucket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/azure-pipelines-for-jira-does-not-display-releases/851208)

**Is there a way to generate Release Notes automatically for Release pipelines in Azure DevOps and source code in Bitbucket?**

I am thinking to migrate to GitHub for this reason, what nice features will I lose? Like [creating a GIT branch from Jira ticket](https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/view-development-information-for-an-issue/)

Comment: Judging from the information already available, it seems that there is no other way

Comment: We have migrated to GitHub and now it works!